# Is the lower Minkowski content additive in any sense?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Proposition 3.3.2 in the book *The geometry of domains in space* by S. Krantz and H. Parks states that if the sets $A$ and $B$ are separated by a positive distance, then $\mathcal{M}_*^K(A \cup B) = \mathcal{M}_*^K(A)  +\mathcal{M}_*^K(B)$, where $\mathcal{M}_*^K$ denotes the  [the $K$-dimensional lower Minkowski content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_content).
The proof is left to the reader.
Is it true, and if yes, how is it proved?

Comment: For $r$ small enough, being close to the union means being close to exactly one of those sets.

Comment: Yes. But how does it help to prove the statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notation follows [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_content).

For $r$ small enough (less than half the separation between $A$ and $B$), we have
$$
\frac{\mu(\{x\;:\;d(x,A \cup B) < r\})}{\alpha(n-m)r^{n-m}}
=\frac{\mu(\{x\;:\;d(x,A) < r\})}{\alpha(n-m)r^{n-m}}
+\frac{\mu(\{x\;:\;d(x,B) < r\})}{\alpha(n-m)r^{n-m}}
$$
but then we take the liminf as $r \to 0^+$.  If the liminf and limsup disagree, we cannot conclude that the liminf of the sum is the sum of the liminfs.  So then what?

**No, it need not be additive.**

For our example, we take the $1$-dimensional lower Minkowski content in $\mathbb R^2$.  For a set $A \subseteq \mathbb R^2$
$$
M^1_*(A) = \liminf_{r \to 0+}\frac{\mu(\{x: d(x,A)<r\})}{2r}
\tag{1}$$
The denominator here is the one-dimensional measure of a $1$-ball of radius $r$; and $\mu$ is $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

We will first consider the self-similar set $A$ in the plane: three maps are similarities with ratio $1/3$ centered at the vertices of the equilateral triangle with side $1$.  We have chosen this so that its Hausdorff dimension (and Minkowski dimension) is $1$.  Here is a picture:
[image: alim]

Now consider the set $A_r := \{x : d(x,A) < r\}$ for various values of $r$, $0<r<1/2$:

[image: a1o2]
[image: a1o3]
[image: a1o5]
[image: a1o6]

Because of the self-similarity, when $r$ shrinks by factor $1/3$, the area of $A_r$ also shrinks by factor $1/3$.  (The first and last of these pictures have $r=1/2$ and $r=1/6$ to illustrate this.)  It follows (as Lalley first observed) that
$$
\mu(A_r) = p(-\log_3 r) \cdot r,\qquad 0 < r < \frac{1}{2}
$$
where $p$ is a function with period $1$.  So $p(-\log_3 r)$ is
something like this:

[image: graph]

We can observe by computing two of these values accurately enough that function $p$ is not constant.  So this is a case with limsup and liminf different in $(1)$.

Now for our set $B$ we take a copy of $A$, translated far away so there is no overlap, and expanded by a factor $q$.  Then
$$
\mu(B_r) = q^2 \mu(A_{r/q}) 
= q^2 p(-\log_3 r+\log_3 q) \cdot r,\qquad 0 < r < \frac{1}{2}
$$
So that we translate the argument of funtion $p$ and multiply by a constant factor.  Now we choose the factor $q$ so that, in the translation of $p$, the minimum of $p$ concides with the maximum of translated $p$:

[image: graph2]

When we do this, the liminf of the sum is not the sum of the liminf.

Comment: Exactly, the problem is that the liminf is not additive.

Comment: Lalley's idea to apply the Renewal Theorem to self-similar sets should let us construct a counterexample.  I will think about it.